# How to organize python package file structure for development and deployment?

Tags: python, package, project-organization

For a Python package I am developing, I have my package contents organized under a src/ subdir like so:

```
mylib/
    dist/
    docs/
    src/
        __init__.py
        foo/
            __init__.py
            foo1.py
            ...
        bar/
            __init__.py
            bar1.py
            ...
        ...              
    README.rst
    pyproject.toml
    requirements.txt
```

Building a wheel with python build and deployment works, but on my dev machine, I would like to import the new package right from the development directory rather than local-installing it every time I make a change. How do I skip the src/ directory from the import statement? I.e., in Python, I would like to be able to do

```
>>> from mylib import foo
```

rather than

```
>>> from mylib.src import foo
```

How do I do that?

Comment: How about prepending [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys_path_init.html)?

Comment: Adding src/ to the sys.path would not result in the desired shape of the import statement.

Comment: But I believe I have found a way - adding a subdir mylib/ under src/ and moving source files there. Only then I have to add mylib\src to the sys.path.

Comment: Yep, was just going to suggest it :)

Comment: I think I can just drop the src/ folder and rename it to mylib/ , that is, have a mylib/mylib folder.

Comment: Python Packaging User Guide describes both approaches and their differences: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/